# Overload an operator by using a generic approach

Tags: c++

How can I overload an operator by using a generic approach?
I have this situation:

```
struct sortByDesc1 {
    bool operator() (const pair<int, int> &left, const pair<int, int> &right) {
        return left.second > right.second;
    }
};
```

Change the operator `>` to `<`

```
struct sortByAsc1 {
    bool operator() (const pair<int, int> &left, const pair<int, int> &right) {
        return left.second < right.second;
    }
};
```

Small change in the data type `pair<int, int>` to `pair<float, float>`

```
struct sortByDesc2 {
    bool operator() (const pair<float, float> &left, const pair<float, float> &right) {
        return left.second > right.second;
    }
};
```

Example of use

```
vector< pair<int, int> > vec;
sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), sortByAsc1());
```

I want a generic function, is this possible?
Eg.:

```
# Abstracting
sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), generic(asc, int));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a template:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2=T1, bool Desc=False>
struct sortBySecond
{
    bool operator() (const std::pair<T1, T2> &l, const std::pair<T1, T2> &r)
    {
        bool ret=l.second<right.second;
        // since Desc is known at compile time, any decent compiler will optimize
        // away the conditional
        return Desc?!ret:ret;
    }
};

sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), sortBySecond<int, int, False>());
```

---

As pointed out by *@Kerrek SB*, you can make this more generic by allowing a custom comparison functor to be used instead of just allowing `<` (and reversing it if necessary):

```
template<typename T1, typename T2=T1, typename compFunc=std::less<T2> >
struct sortBySecondEx
{
    bool operator() (const std::pair<T1, T2> &l, const std::pair<T1, T2> &r)
    {
        bool ret=compFunc(l.second,right.second);
        return Desc?!ret:ret;
    }
};

// Ascending
sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), sortBySecondEx<int, int, std::less<int> >());
// Descending
sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), sortBySecondEx<int, int, std::greater<int> >());
```

Comment: Bool? Why not a templates predicate?

Comment: @KerrekSB: KISS, especially when OP clearly is inexperienced in templates; also, this is just the functionality he wanted to achieve (ordering by `<`, invertible if necessary).

Comment: `std::less` is a template -> `typename compFunc=std::less<ARG>` (or template template parameter)

Comment: Elegant answer. However the compiler returns an error in `sort (vec.begin (), vec.end (), sortBySecond <int, int, false>);`, "saying expected primary-expression before ')' token"

Comment: Now it should be fixed.